# Take all value between punctuation containing a word from a same cells [Python & SQL]

Tags: python, mysql, sql, concatenation

I would like take from the same cell with this design :

```
",abcdefghif - P0 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P2 - site - location, **xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location**, **xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location**, xwoznehdy - P1 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P9 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P8 - site - location, **xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location**, xwoznehdy - P6 - site - location, "
```

I try to take all value between 2 ',' who have the value 'P7' for an other columns.

I tried with `regex_replace` : `regexp_replace("column name", concat_ws('',',','[^,]','P7','[^,]'), '')` but it's not working.
i'm not enough good and after many hours to find a solution, i ask you to help me lol.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: What is the RDBMS? Maria? MySQL? T-SQL?

Comment: It's MySQL and Python

Comment: Maybe all you need is https://ideone.com/RjIM0C? `[chunk for chunk in text.split(',') if "P7" in chunk]`

Comment: Show us the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the simplest approach is to use a list comprehension in a Python script. However, if you are looking for a pure SQL solution, then you can use `regexp_substr` in a `cte`:

```
with recursive tbl(s) as (
   select ',abcdefghif - P0 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P2 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P1 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P9 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P8 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P7 - site - location, xwoznehdy - P6 - site - location, '
),
cts(s, c) as (
    select s, length(s) - length(regexp_replace(s, 'P7', 'X')) from tbl
),
cte(s, c, m) as (
    select s, c - 1, regexp_substr(s, '[\\s\\w\\-]+P7[\\s\\w\\-]+', 1, c) from cts
    union all
    select s, c - 1, regexp_substr(s, '[\\s\\w\\-]+P7[\\s\\w\\-]+', 1, c) from cte where c > 0
)
select m from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if Python is available:

```py
(?:[^,\s][^,]*)?P7(?:[^,]*[^,\s])?
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/zFiIwm/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,\s]                   any character except: ',', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  P7                       'P7'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,\s]                   any character except: ',', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```